# Combined 2 columns into one column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm a beginner to Postgres and need to do something like this.
My Postgres query output has 2 columns. I need to combine these two like below.

Column 1:

```
A
B
C
```

Column 2:

```
D
D
D
```

Output Column:

```
A
B
C
D
```

(all values from column 1 and distinct values from column 2)

Is this possible in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 15):

Hi there is one fancy way:

```
select distinct unnest(array[
        column1
        , column2
    ])
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this :

```
 select  col    from (
   select Column1 as col   from <your table >
    union all 
    select distinct Column2 as col   from <your table>
) as myview order by col
```

Comment: nop. It can not be used union because it directly hit to the query performance. I optimized my query to gain data within 200ms. but if i use union (divide my query to 2 parts) it takes near to 600ms. is there any method to do this without using union? Below I mentioned my query.

Answer (score 0):

Put your original query into a common table expression then aggregate the distinct values of each column:

```
with data (fromzoneid, fromzoneid2) as ( 
  ... your complete original query goes here ...
)
select string_agg(distinct c1, '') as zoneid
from (
  select t1.c1
  from data
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(fromzoneid, '') as t1 (c1)
  union 
  select t2.c1
  from data
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(fromzoneid2, '') as t2 (c1)
)  t;
```

---

### Attention

The above assumes that your query only returns a single row. My solution will aggregate the values for **all rows** that are returned by your query! If you query returns more than row, the unique characters of all rows are combined into a single column and single row!

If you don't want that, you need an additional column in your query that can be used for a group by statement

Something like:

```
with data (id, fromzoneid, fromzoneid2) as ( 
  ... your complete original query goes here ...
)
select id, string_agg(distinct c1, '') as zoneid
from (
  select data.id, t1.c1
  from data
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(fromzoneid, '') as t1 (c1)
  union 
  select data.id, t2.c1
  from data
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(fromzoneid2, '') as t2 (c1)
)  t
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have 3 colums and want to combine the rows into one and want no duplicated values. There for I merged them in the first step via `col1 || '#' || col2 || '#' || col3`. Then I used the `string_to_array` function to split the string into array to use `unnest` in the last step. After all I can use `DISTINCT` over my result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(string_to_array(col1 || '#' || col2 || '#' || col3, '#')) FROM my_table;
```