# PostgreSQL select uniques from three different columns

Tags: postgresql, unique

I have one large table 100m+ rows and two smaller ones 2m rows ea. All three tables have a column of company names that need to be sent out to an API for matching. I want to select the strings from each column and then combine into a single column of unique strings.

I'm using a version of this response, but unsurprisingly the performance is very slow. [Combined 2 columns into one column SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268999/combined-2-columns-into-one-column-sql)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    unnest(string_to_array(upper(t.buyer) || '#' || upper(a.aw_supplier_name) || '#' || upper(b.supplier_source_string), '#')) 
FROM
    tenders t,
    awards a,
    banking b
;
```

Any ideas on a more performant way to achieve this?

Update: the banking table is the largest table with 100m rows.

Comment: Note: you are attempting a carthesian join resulting in  100M x 100 x 100 := 1E12 tuples,  (and then perform distinct on it) .  Is this what you really want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming PostgreSQL 9.6 and borrowing the select from rd_nielsen's answer, the following should give you a comma delimited string of the distinct names.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT UPPER(T.buyer) NAMES
    FROM tenders T

    UNION

    SELECT UPPER(A.aw_supplier_name) NAMES
    FROM awards A

    UNION

    SELECT UPPER(b.supplier_source_string) NAMES
    FROM banking b
    )
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(cte.names), ',')
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1):

To get just a list of the combined names from all three tables, you could instead `union` together the selections from each table, like so:

```
select
    upper(t.buyer)
from
    tenders t
union
select
    upper(a.aw_supplier_name)
from
    awards a
union
select
    upper(b.supplier_source_string)
from
    banking b
;
```